# What does 0; means in javascript

Tags: javascript

Looking at grunt-strip plugin to remove console.logs. I realized that it replaces console.log statements with `0;`. Does `0;` have any effect?

Comment: Can you post a few lines of code as an before / after example?
`0;` doesn't do anything in JS

Comment: They could have replaced it with `''` (empty) ...

Comment: It's basically a `void` type of thing, it doesn't do anything meaningful.

Comment: Do you mean `return 0;`?

Comment: @Mr.Alien no it is just 0; statement.

Answer (score 6):

It doesn't have any effect, no. JS evaluates `0` and nothing picks up the result. The idea is that removing `console.*` (with a simple replace by nothing) might break code like this:

```
if(condition)
    console.log('');

functionCall();
```

Would become (with reformatting for emphasis...)

```
if(condition)
    functionCall();
```

So it's replaced by a dummy statement.

```
if(condition)
    0; // Does nothing

functionCall();
```

Also, code checking if the console is present will return false because `0` is falsy.

```
if(console) { // Not executed when replaced by if(0)
    // debugging action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> **How it's done**
>
> Right now, the logic consists of a simple replacement of your selected
>   nodes with a falsy statement (0). This is proving to work in all
>   reasonable situations and alleviates the need for complex rewrite
>   logic.
>
> At some later date that rewrite logic may be important, but the cost
>   vs reward isn't there right now.

Source: https://github.com/jsoverson/grunt-strip